# codeigniter routing (simple blog example)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was trying to figure out the codeginter framework and follow their simple blog tutorial.

At the moment i'm getting "Object not found! ... Error 403" message and here is what I did:

- in my httdocs I placed the folder "blogCI/CodeIgniter[...]"
- inside the controllers i have blog.php file

blog.php is as follows (surrounded with php tags):

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller{
function Blog()
{ 
echo "Blog constructor";
}
}
```

I started up localhost server (XAMPP), can see the xampp's page, but then I can't seem to access my own page and make it to print "Blog constructor"

```
"http://localhost/blogCI/CodeIgniter/index.php/blog/index"
"http://localhost/blogCI/CodeIgniter/index.php/blog.php/index"
"http://localhost/blogCI/CodeIgniter/blog.php/index"
```

...
and alot of other combination links.

The only way I could get my page to display the message, if in config/router I would make the blog.php a default controller, but that's not what I want.

Has anyone came across this before?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an index function in your blog controller. Also you shouldn't use the old constructor method if you need a constructor use __construct.

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        //do constructor stuff
    }

    function index()
    { 
        echo "Blog index";
    }
}
```

Then to access go to

```
http://localhost/blogCI/CodeIgniter/index.php/blog
```

Comment: hi, thank you for fast reply - but I still get the same thing :/

Comment: Are you using an htaccess file? If so then remove the index.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check file permissions of your CI project